# Unable to discover SpringBoot 2.1.1 with Consul (SpringCloud Finchley)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I am trying to register a sample SpringBoot service to consul with the help of SpringCloud, but without success **when using latest versions**.

Versions with success :

- SpringBoot : 2.0.0.RELEASE
- Cloud : Finchley.RELEASE
- Consul : 1.4.0

Versions **without** success :

- SpringBoot : 2.1.1.RELEASE
- Cloud : Finchley.RELEASE
- Consul : 1.4.0

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.ote.test</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <!--version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version-->                    
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I start consul with the command : consul agent -dev

My service provides "/health" endpoint and declare @EnableDiscoveryClient

My configuration is (application.yml or bootstrap.yml, same result):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: server
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        tags: test
        enabled: true
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
        healthCheckPath: /health
        healthCheckInterval: 5s
```

When I start the service with SpringBoot 2.0.0.RELEASE, it works well. 
When I start the exactly same service with SpringBoot 2.1.1.RELEASE, the service is not registered to consul (and cannot be discovered by any client)

What is wrong or missing ?

Comment: Finchley is not compatible with boot 2.1.x. You'll need to try with Greenwich.M3

Comment: Thanks Spencer, it works well. Basically, how can I know which cloud version is compatible to any boot version.

Comment: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud